# #frame driver is not uniform/linear

Tags: animation, drivers, fcurves

I am using `#frame` to drive the `Y`-coordinate of my Voronoi texture in Blender.
However, the resulting animation is not linear, but seems to ease-in (I can't add a gif, since the size is too large).

This it the material

[image: Materia]

I did not change anything in the driver editor, and `#frame` or `frame` sound to me as if they should do linear interpolation by default? This is what I get when I rightclick on `frame` and select `Open Drivers Editor`: (the driver is not even shown)

[image: driver editor]

Any hints appreciated!

Comment: I think I debugged something similar in the past… Try removing the driver, **going to frame 1** and adding the driver there. If that doesn't work, upload your file to https://blend-exchange.com/ and I'll figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

> the driver is not even shown

By default, the graph and driver editors show only what's selected. If you need to see a keyframe or a driver from a node, you need to select that node:

[image]

> the resulting animation is not linear, but seems to ease-in

It seems to, but how can you tell for sure?

With a Voronoi on the default plane, adding just `1` to the Y Location moves the texture so much that you don't even see what was there at zero:

[image: demo gif]

Using the `#frame` is basically doing that for each frame. It just outputs the current scene's frame number.

Unless you divide it to slow it down, or dezoom the texture enough to see the whole thing moving, you only see big jumps of textures that can easily "seem" different from what they are, much like a car's tire can seem to roll backwards when it rolls forwards fast enough.

Divided using `#frame/10`:

[image: divided gif]

Dezoomed using scale at 20:

[image: demo dezoomed]